# Problem with rename-window in tmux

Tags: command-line, zsh, tmux

I have a tmux session called "session1" and two windows both with the name "zsh".

I wanted to change the name of my current window to "TeX_Code". Steps were:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. `:`
3. `rename-window 'TeX_Code'`

Which changed the name accordingly. But when I pressed enter in the prompt the name was changed back to `zsh`.

How do I keep the name?

=======Edit last lines of my .zshrc

```
#using for tmux and vi compare http://www.economyofeffort.com/2014/07/04/zsh/
    export TERM=xterm-256color
    [ -n "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=screen-256color

    DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat ~/.zshrc`

Comment: my full rc file has nearly 3800 lines. I got it with wget -O ~/.zshrc http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/zsh/zshrc   the last lines were manually added by myself

Comment: Right, doesn't works with your zshrc

Comment: Then thank you very much for your help! Since it is not worth the work for me to rewrite this rc file. I will  ignore the problem for a moment and making up my own rc file from scratch.

Comment: OK everything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is your zsh.

Edit your `.zshrc` via

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and add

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

at the end of the file. After that, restart your session.

Comment: I am sorry but this does not work for me.

Comment: Restart your tmux session. It works.

Comment: I even logged out completely. It did not work. (the tmux session is locally on my machine)